# Flutter printing text over an image in the same position with different device

Tags: flutter

I wrote this code

```
Stack(children: [
    Image.asset(
         'assets/images/letter.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    ),
                      
    Positioned(
        left: 0.15 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        top: 0.73 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Text(
            'TEST',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 0.02 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
    )), 
]
```

that display an image with text over it. The problem is that the text is write in different position  with different devices (ex. mobile or tablet). How can i write in the same position of the image if the resolution change?

I try to change the Positioned "left" and "top" tags with absolute value but nothing changed

Comment: You can try removing `MediaQuery` and using `Align` widget instead of Positioned. Also You need to provide fixed/relative over Stack widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Column or Rows for positions you'r text also SizeBox you can use.if you have any issue feel to free ask anything.

Wrap you'r text widget with column or row look at bellow code segment,

```
     Positioned(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 275, top: 20),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text('Test'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: what i've to wrap into a column or row or sizebox ?The image or the positioned

Comment: Look at updated answer

Comment: nothing changed. The text is in different position of the under image between different devices. Is the problem on the Image widget?

Comment: Put you'r application image and give new updated code segment

Comment: do you need the image?

Comment: If you can give image it's easy to found you'r issue

Comment: It's a normal png

Comment: No u miss understood, I want you'r  image of you'r app while run on emulator

Comment: I not need look you'r assets images

Comment: sorry but i cannot give my screenshot :(

Comment: Can u put you'r updated code snipts.

Comment: I want look only you'r  Positioned( ) widget only.

Comment: Positioned(
                          child: Padding(padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,top:15)
                          child: Row(children: [Text(
                            'Test',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )]))),

Comment: Actually I cannot imagine you'r widget tree without demo screen